# Does ES6 target allow typescript + systemjs to support circular references?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, systemjs, circular-dependency

I know similar questions have been asked before (e.g., [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444436/circular-type-references-in-typescript), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306749/typescript-inheritance-and-circular-dependencies-in-systemjs)). However, they do not mention ES6, which the systemjs docs imply is a solution to the problem ([3](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/ee392b91a54cb2865d4aa10b1d2843eb501185d3/docs/module-formats.md)).

So my question is: If I tell the typescript compiler to target ES6 and emit "system" modules, and use systemjs as my module loader, will that support circular dependencies?

If not, any approaches that supports circular dependencies in Typescript are welcome (via whatever transpiler, loader, etc., are required).

(I have already seen advice to modify the code to remove circular dependencies. It would be very harmful to our system design and I would like to avoid it.)

Comment: does this help? https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1272

Comment: Thanks, that is potentially relevant, but our issue is only with our own typescript classes, so we can build them all for a single module loader/framework.